# woocommerce remove_cart_item работает не со всеми товарами

Tags: php, wordpress, ajax, woocommerce

Пытаюсь удалять товары из корзины ajax запросом , функция remove_cart_item в случаях с конкретными товарами возвращает false в строке
`exit (json_encode(WC()->cart->remove_cart_item($_POST['id']))); //$_POST['id'] это ключ продукта`
то же самое иногда случается с добавлением , подскажите в чем может быть дело, уже 2 дня ищу как пофиксить

Comment: А где ваш код то?

Answer (score 0):

В общем метод `remove_cart_item` объекта `WC_Cart` возвращает false только в том случае если такого товара нет в корзине. Подробнее: https://wp-kama.ru/function/WC_Cart::remove_cart_item

Возможно вы используете вариантивные товары, там для каждой вариации свой уникальный id. Либо же в $_POST['id'] нет нужного значения

Comment: не , вариаций продуктов нету, я тоже думал возможно удаляемого продукта нет в корзине , тогда проблема в том что он числится и выводится при просмотре корзины а при удалении его там нет и небыло , как такое может быть. Содержимое корзины получаю с помощью 
global $woocommerce;
$items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
удаляются продукты по ключу который при выводе есть. Тоесть в целом этот код иногда срабатывает но это серьезный баг

Comment: показывайте код целиком. Это не сайт по гаданию на кофейной гуще)

Comment: http://skrinshoter.ru/s/210420/AgF3vJax?a вывод карточек продуктов корзины ___
http://skrinshoter.ru/s/210420/ZS79G2CU?a запрос на сервер ___
http://skrinshoter.ru/s/210420/TS62nOZE?a обработка ajax запроса ___
http://skrinshoter.ru/s/210420/2x5oaHve?a ответ сервера. Спасибо